# Create Integration Test Project into ASP.NET Core application

Tags: asp.net-core, integration-testing

I have created an ASP.NET Core WebApi project. Trying to add Integration Test Project following [Integration tests in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-5.0) article.
According to the [sample](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/tree/master/aspnetcore/test/integration-tests/samples/3.x/IntegrationTestsSample) project, I have added another web application for the Test project and configured like the sample project. Then I deleted the program.cs and startup.cs files.
But when I build the project got the following error:

> Error CS5001  Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable
> for an entry point

My folder structure is like this:
[image]

Comment: See this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41156691/asp-net-core-program-does-not-contain-a-static-main-method-suitable-for-an-en) may helpful.

Comment: If I put Output Type as class Class Library, this works fine but the sample project's output type is Console Application. How the do that?

Comment: How about change to `"buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": false
  },`

Comment: Or add `public static void Main(string[] args) => WebApplication.Run<Startup>(args);`to your startup.